# Confusion about Kähler condition

Tags: symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I have a question regarding Kähler manifolds and proposition 2.63 of the book: "Introduction to symplectic topology" of McDuff and Salamon.

According to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold), a
Kähler manifold is a symplectic manifold with a compatible almost-integrable structure,
but according to proposition 2.63 of McDuff (see image), every symplectic manifold admits an almost complex compatible structure.

I do not understand how this statements are compatible, since there are well known examples of non-Kähler symplectic manifolds. In particular, symplectic manifolds which have topological obstructions to being Kähler, which means, the problem is not a confusion about the choice of the metric.

So my question is,  what am I getting wrong? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: To be Kahler, you need an **integrable** almost complex structure.

Comment: Ooohh crap. I feel so stupid now. Thanks man!